# error in migrating django project with mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

when i want to migrate my django project with mysql as database i get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[] NOT NULL, `source` varchar(200) NOT NULL)' at line 1")
```

this is my models.py file :

```
from django_mysql.models import ListCharField
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class news(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='title of the news', max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='news text')
    tags = ListCharField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=200),
                         max_length=200)
    source = models.URLField(verbose_name='news source url')

    #class Meta:
    #    ordering = ['?']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

what should o do to fix it?

these are versions for packages:

```
Django==4.2.4
django-mysql==4.11.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
mysqlclient==2.2.0
```

and this is mysql version installed in my system.

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

i tried to upgrade mysql but i get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```